# AFNetworking - does its HTTP request send with cookies by default?

Tags: ios5, ios6, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, nsurlrequest

I am trying to debug a http get request i sent via AFNetworking's AFJSONRequestOperation to see if the cookies are being sent correctly. However, i dont see any cookies in http header. Can some expert help me out here? thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cookie to your `AFHTTPClient` or it's subclass with the following line

```
[_httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Cookie" value:@"cookie=value"];
```

I've tried this with my server and it works. It can clearly catch the cookie named `cookie` and it's related `value`.